# Highcharts multiple axis gauge with 2 dials with different radii

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts you can add a second axis and a second dial to a gauge and you can change the radius of the dials together but I cannot find a way to change the radius of each dial separately.

I want my `plotOptions` to look something like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    gauge: {
        dial: [
            {
                radius: "45%",
                rearLength: "0%"
            },
            {
                radius: "90%",
                rearLength: "-70%"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

where only this seems to have any effect but it effect both dials

```
plotOptions: {
    gauge: {
        dial: {
            radius: "45%",
            rearLength: "0%"
        }
    }
}
```

i tried making `plotOptions` itself an array and then `gauge`. The API docs don't seem to offer a way to do this as all options beneath `plotOptions` seem to be singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the dial options into the actual series options: http://jsfiddle.net/9rZLH/

```
series: [{
    data: [80],
    dial: {
        radius: "45%",
        rearLength: "0%"
    }
},{
    data: [70],
    dial: {
        radius: "90%",
        rearLength: "-70%"
    }
}]
```

Edit: the [Highcharts Clock example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-clock) also does it this way.